# SIGSEGV debugging: Where is the update() method defined in cocos2d-iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to tackle a `SIGSEGV` signal error in `cocos2d-iphone 1.0.1`. I must note that, despite several hours trying, I couldn't actually replicate the crash. I only know that it happens because of the testers.

I've collected as much info as I could. First of all, here is the TestFlight backtrace:

[image]

Great. So let's take a look at `CCScheduler`'s `tick` method. It is fairly large, so I have here only the block of code where the error occurs (at the bottom of the question you can see the full method):

```
for( elt->timerIndex = 0; elt->timerIndex < elt->timers->num; elt->timerIndex++) {
    elt->currentTimer = elt->timers->arr[elt->timerIndex];
    elt->currentTimerSalvaged = NO;

    impMethod( elt->currentTimer, updateSelector, dt);

    if( elt->currentTimerSalvaged ) {
        [elt->currentTimer release];
    }

    elt->currentTimer = nil;
}
```

And the exact error line is

```
impMethod( elt->currentTimer, updateSelector, dt);
```

Good. So we got the culprit line.

Let's see, `impMethod` is of type `TICK_IMP`, which is defined as

```
typedef void (*TICK_IMP)(id, SEL, ccTime);
```

Hm. I don't see any problem with `impMethod( elt->currentTimer, updateSelector, dt)` itself.

Looking closely, my best guess is that `elt->currentTimer` could be problematic.

At first, I thought that maybe if `elt` is a `NULL` pointer, calling `elt->currentTimer` could cause a segmentation fault. However, I've recently been told that even if `elt` was `NULL`, sending a message to it wouldn't cause a `SIGSEGV` error.

I have confirmed this because I eventually wrapped the method with `if (elt != NULL)` and it still happened, so the problem must be something else.

Running out of clues, it occurred to me that this code, as it is, cannot be causing the error. It must be something obscure somewhere else in my code.

Let's see. If I perform an `NSLog` before the culprit line like this:

```
NSLog(@"[%@ %@]" , [elt->target class],NSStringFromSelector(updateSelector));
```

I can tell what was the last scheduled object to be updated, and even get the corresponding method!

After making my testers crash again, I finally got this result:

`[Game update]`

Sweet. `Game` is the main game scene, so it seems like the problem is related to such scene.

But wait. There is no such method `update` for my scene. I never implemented something like that.

Then I figured that since `Game` is a `CCScene` object, maybe `CCScene` does have such method. But I see its implementation and it doesn't. But wait, `CCScene` is a subclass of `CCNode`! So let's take a look at `CCNode`.

... There are no `update` methods in `CCNode` either.

I did find something curious about `CCNode`:

```
-(void) scheduleUpdate;
```

Which apparently is in charge of scheduling the `update` method to be called once per frame - and it does. Here's a particular line of such procedure:

```
[target methodForSelector:updateSelector];
```

Where `target` is supposed to be `Game` and `updateSelector` is `@selector(update:)`.

However, this doesn't make any sense: **where** is this `update` method supposed to be implemented? I do not find it anywhere in `CCNode`. Therefore, how could it possibly schedule such method?

Normally, I would say that this is what causes the error - that we're scheduling a method that is not implemented, thus causing a `SIGSEGV` error. However, this is plain weird, because if that was true, then it should be crashing **all the time** - but it doesn't.

And this is as far as I got trying to debug this error. What am I missing?

I know that you can't tell me where the problem is, but I believe that I got an important lead and you can shed some light on it: **where is `update` implemented in cocos2d**?

---

This is the full code of the `tick` method in `CCScheduler`, just in case:

```
-(void) tick: (ccTime) dt {
    updateHashLocked = YES;

    if( timeScale_ != 1.0f )
        dt *= timeScale_;

        // Iterate all over the Updates selectors
        tListEntry *entry, *tmp;

    // updates with priority < 0
    DL_FOREACH_SAFE( updatesNeg, entry, tmp ) {
        if( ! entry->paused && !entry->markedForDeletion )
            entry->impMethod( entry->target, updateSelector, dt );
    }

    // updates with priority == 0
    DL_FOREACH_SAFE( updates0, entry, tmp ) {
        if( ! entry->paused && !entry->markedForDeletion )
        {
            entry->impMethod( entry->target, updateSelector, dt );
        }
    }

    // updates with priority > 0
    DL_FOREACH_SAFE( updatesPos, entry, tmp ) {
        if( ! entry->paused  && !entry->markedForDeletion )
            entry->impMethod( entry->target, updateSelector, dt );
    }

    // Iterate all over the  custome selectors
    for(tHashSelectorEntry *elt=hashForSelectors; elt != NULL; ) {

        currentTarget = elt;
        currentTargetSalvaged = NO;

        if( ! currentTarget->paused ) {

            // The 'timers' ccArray may change while inside this loop.
            for( elt->timerIndex = 0; elt->timerIndex < elt->timers->num; elt->timerIndex++) {
                elt->currentTimer = elt->timers->arr[elt->timerIndex];
                elt->currentTimerSalvaged = NO;

                impMethod( elt->currentTimer, updateSelector, dt);

                if( elt->currentTimerSalvaged ) {
                    // The currentTimer told the remove itself. To prevent the timer from
                    // accidentally deallocating itself before finishing its step, we retained
                    // it. Now that step is done, it's safe to release it.
                    [elt->currentTimer release];
                }

                elt->currentTimer = nil;
            }
        }

        if (elt != NULL) {
            // elt, at this moment, is still valid
            // so it is safe to ask this here (issue #490)
            elt = elt->hh.next;

            // only delete currentTarget if no actions were scheduled during the cycle (issue #481)
            if( currentTargetSalvaged && currentTarget->timers->num == 0 )
                [self removeHashElement:currentTarget];
        }
    }

    // delete all updates that are morked for deletion
    // updates with priority < 0
    DL_FOREACH_SAFE( updatesNeg, entry, tmp ) {
        if(entry->markedForDeletion )
        {
            [self removeUpdateFromHash:entry];
        }
    }

    // updates with priority == 0
    DL_FOREACH_SAFE( updates0, entry, tmp ) {
        if(entry->markedForDeletion )
        {
            [self removeUpdateFromHash:entry];
        }
    }

    // updates with priority > 0
    DL_FOREACH_SAFE( updatesPos, entry, tmp ) {
        if(entry->markedForDeletion )
        {
            [self removeUpdateFromHash:entry];
        }
    }

    updateHashLocked = NO;
    currentTarget = nil;
}
```

Comment: update: is supposed to be implemented in the class where you do scheduleUpdate. If you don't call that check if you run scheduleSelector: anywhere with the wrong signature - it should be update: with a single float parameter but your log shows update without colon/parameter. Also ask if testers use a 64bit device like iphone 5S because there are potential issues in cocos2d v1 and v2 on 64bit devices.

Comment: since the error is in the custom selectors block of the method it's definitely a selector that was scheduled with one of the scheduleSelector:... variants. Check all of those, specifically search your code for any uses of "@selector(update)"

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: Thank you for the response, I will look into that. As for the 64bit devices, I think that it once happened with a 4S (which I guess is 32 bits). Anyway, is dropping `arm64` from the valid architectures enough to make it behave like a normal 32 bit device?

Comment: yes yes yes, absolutely do not include the arm64 architecture in any build target of a cocos2d-iphone v1 or v2 app. v3 works fine and is tested with 64bit iphones.